# DIV stylesheet attributes?

Tags: stylesheet, html

I am new to div stylesheet and i only discovered how to use :

margin-top/left/right/bottom.

What is the **position** used for ?

What is **left/right/top/bottom** attrib used for?

What is **display** used for?

Is there any other attrib which i need to take note of/usage for positioning my div ?

Regards

Comment: In addition to the answers, it's important to note that none of those properties are specific to the `div` element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_position.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_left.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_display.asp
- http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: The whole [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com) site is a great reference for this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

margin is in relation to the closest container while left/right... is in relation to the entire page.

Display determines if the object is visible/hidden or how the element behaves. Like display: inline means the elements will display on the same horizontal plane if possible.